# Is there a way to disable voice search?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, google-voice-actions

Since updating to Jelly Bean, my Nexus S had a problem with voice search starting up all the time (about every 30 secs).

Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 8):

far easier, folks:

```
settings > language & input > keyboard & input methods: DISABLE 'google voice typing'
```

Answer (score 3):

In ICS, to disable an app you can go to Settings -> Apps -> All tabs -> click the app name and click "Disable". I assume its same for JB as well.

Comment: You cannot disable every app in this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to settings-> applications and choose "all" tab to see the list of all apps and services. Scroll down to the end and choose voice search, which brings you an option to stop the service.

If your device is rooted, you can go one more step ahead and even uninstall the voice search app. In that case, you may need to have app like Link2SD.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Applications" in settings menu. Find the 'voice search' and then long press until you get an option for app info. Then you will have two choices: one is **force stop** and the other is **disable**. If you choose disable, it will say that by disabling this may cause some apps not to work properly but so far my apps have been working.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Settings→Application Manager→All*, scroll down to *Google Text to Speech*, and *Clear data and disable*. Also you can uncheck *Show Notifications*.

If you like, you can install "Jeanny" (wich is pretty cool too) and then install "SVOX English Grace Voice" or "IVONA Text to Speech HQ" to make her talk. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I add that on the Galaxy S3, it can be located at Application Manager\All\com.google.android.voicesearch.

I brought up the AppInfo, Force stop, then Disabled it.